# After ajax request jquery can't find the correct div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

For my project I load a html file to populate the `div`s by directly inserting html content to the `div`s. The problem is, I have many elements which has div inside them with same id. This causes problem to select correct one i.e. `$('#div_name')`. It always finds wrong one.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fBsF7/2/)

How can I solve this problem.

Comment: First of all, you should give unique id to all elements

Answer (score 0):

**update**

```
$('.to_be_filled:eq(1)').children('#graph_container').css('background-color', 'red');
$('.to_be_filled:eq(2)').children('#graph_container').css('background-color', 'green');
```

since the eq()  supplied index is zero-based, to select 2nd and 3rd you need to select eq(1),eq(2)...

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fBsF7/3/)

Comment: But how? I always download a static html and put that content inside the divs.

Comment: if such is the case..thn can you post your static HTML contents here